# Ggvegan autoplot plot boundaries

Tags: r, ggplot2, vegan

I have done CCA- and RDA analysis in R with vegan and used autoplot.cca to generate plots. However, the plot boundaries are not constant and adjust autmatically (to what I do not know). Some plots return a horizontally very narrow plot

I have tried some suggestions like adding:

```
autoplot() +
labs(x=NULL, y=NULL) +
scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0, 0)) +
scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0))
```

But this doesn't resolve anything. The code for plotting is below. I'm not making any fancy calls on formatting earlier in the code.

```
print(autoplot(my.cca, geom = "text", title = paste(i, "_sites_params_Wetter"), layers = c("sites", "biplot")) +
           #geom_point(aes(my.cca)) +
           #geom_hline(yintercept = 0) +
           #geom_vline(xintercept = 0) +
           theme(legend.position = "none") 
       )
```

Example output shared in link (don't have enough rep to post images):

[image]

I essentially plot in a loop, and the plots vary in area. I would like to be able to control the dimensions of the plotting area, and also make sure all labels are 100% within the area.

How do I do this?

Here is some example code to play with

```
x<-c("vegan", "ggplot2", "ggvegan")

lapply(x, require, character.only = TRUE)

data(package = "vegan")

data(mite)
data(mite.env)

my.cca <- cca(mite ~ ., data=mite.env)

autoplot(my.cca, geom = "text", layers = c("species", "biplot")) +
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

Comment: This may be because the x-axis and y-axis scales need to be identical (otherwise the plots are misleading)

Comment: @RichardTelford Stretching would be warranted in my opinion. But I'll just go with the way it gets plotted automatically I guess.

Comment: @RichardTelford I do feel like the text going outside the borders is troublesome. Is there a way to at least fix the dimensions of the plot area to include the full labels?